# How do I find all classes in a project that extend a particular library?

Tags: java, eclipse, search

I'm looking for a way to find all classes that extend classes from particular library. Is there any way to do this except by manual examination?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the library defines the package com.foo.bar (and subpackages). You should be able to do what you want by doing a Java Search for the "com.foo.bar.*" search string, with "Type" as "Search For" option, and "Implementors" as "Limit To" option.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Eclipse Type Hierarchy view to find subclasses of a particular class. I don't know if you can do it for all classes of a given library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tattletale](http://www.jboss.org/tattletale) to build a report of dependencies. It has two reports called "Classes depends On" and "Classes depends" which list each class and their dependencies. That should be helpful to you.

Answer (score -1):

Just search by import statement your providing by that package from that library

Comment: He's looking for classes extending classes from the library, not just using classes from the library.

Comment: Yes dude, but iam not that much femilar of that option of limit :)